# MySQL - Why is LOAD DATA INFILE replacing data in columns I didn't specify with NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to take a TSV file and 'POST'ed inputs and load the TSV file's contents into a DB table, replacing any existing data for specified columns.  The TSV may contain any number of columns and rows and the 1st row specifies the columns that are supposed to be modified.

My problem concerns data in columns that ARE NOT supposed to be modified when running the code-generated `LOAD DATA INFILE ... REPLACE INTO TABLE ...` MySQL statement.  When I run my code (see below), data of columns that are NOT specified in `$columnsText` (which is generated from the 1st row of the TSV file) end-up getting set to NULL or their default value. On the other hand, data of columns that ARE specified in `$columnsText` have their contents replaced just as intended.

An example of the MySQL statement that is generated by my code and is working as described above is:
`LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\MyProject\\public\\1459772537-cities7.tsv' REPLACE INTO TABLE cities FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES (id,UNLOCODE,name_english,UN_subdiv)` -- for all TSV-file mentioned rows, this statement will update the mentioned columns (id,UNLOCODE,name_english,UN_subdiv) correctly, but then all unmentioned columns for that row will be set to NULL!

How do I modify this code to keep the data of unspecified columns from being set to their default/NULL values?  Or more simply, getting to the root of the problem, how do I fix the MySQL statement that is being generated to achieve my objective?

I'm using PHP with Laravel.

```
// Get file, put it in a folder on the server.
    if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
        echo "POST has file <br>";
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = public_path();
        $file->move($path, $name);
        $pathName= $path .'\\'.$name;
        echo "location: ".$pathName."<br>";

        // Determine whether to use IGNORE OR REPLACE in MySQL query.
        if (isset($_POST['replace']) && $_POST['replace'] == true){
            $ignoreOrReplace = "REPLACE";
        }
        else {$ignoreOrReplace = "IGNORE";}
        echo "ignore or replace: ".$ignoreOrReplace."<br>";

        // Determine columns to insert in DB, based on values of input file's 1st row.
        $columnsText = "";
        if (($handle = fopen("$pathName", "r")) !== FALSE) { //"r" parameter = read-only, w file-pointer at start of file.
            $columns = fgetcsv($handle,0,"\t"); // makes an array of the column names that are in the 1st row of TSV file.
            $firstIteration = true;
            foreach ($columns as $column){
                if ($firstIteration){$firstIteration=false;}
                else {$columnsText .= ",";}
                $columnsText .= $column;
            }
            echo "DB columns to load: ".$columnsText;
            fclose($handle);
        }

        $query = sprintf(
            "LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' %s INTO TABLE %s
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        ESCAPED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES (%s)",
            addslashes($pathName),$ignoreOrReplace,$_POST['mytable'],$columnsText
        );
        echo "<br>Here's the query: ".$query."<br>";

        echo "<br><br> Database update should be complete!<br><br>";
        echo '<a href="/">Return to Home Page</a><br>';
        DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("SET sql_mode ='';"); // I forgot what this does.
        return DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
```

Comment: What's happening is the [intended behaviour of `REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html): "If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows." So your new row (with no values for some columns) replaces your existing row entirely. You may want to upload to a "staging" table then merge from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) states:

> If you specify `REPLACE`, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row. See Section 13.2.8, [“REPLACE Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html).

[`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) is not [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). `REPLACE` is a MySQL extension to the SQL that first **deletes** the row if it exists, then it **inserts** the new one.

On [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html), MySQL uses the default values for the fields that are not provided in the query. These fields probably default to `NULL` in your case.

There is no way to update the existing rows using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

I suggest you to create a working table and use it only for the purpose of loading data into it as follows:

1. [`TRUNCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html) it before using it.
2. `LOAD DATA INFILE` in it.
3. Join it against the table you want to update and use [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) on the join to copy the fields you need from the working table to the final table.
4. Use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) to get from the join the rows that are not in the final table and insert them.
5. `TRUNCATE` it.

Don't delete the table after it is used, you'll need it again next time. The last step aims to keep its disk usage at a minimum; the table definition doesn't take much space.

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me on the right track.  I have provided my exact code as an additional answer in case it is helpful to anyone using PHP/Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by axiac is broadly-speaking the correct answer.
In case it is useful to anyone, I have included below the specific code (PHP/Laravel/MySQL) that solved my problem.  I can't necessarily say this is the most efficient way to solve this problem, but it it working! :)

```
    // (1) setup
    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

    // (2) Get file, put it in a folder on the server.
    if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
        $file = Input::file('file');
    }
    else {
        echo "<br>Input file not found! Please review inputed information.<br>";
        return null;
    }
    $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = public_path();
    $file->move($path, $name);
    $pathName= $path .'\\'.$name;
    echo "Input file location: ".$pathName."<br>";

    // (3) Determine main table and staging table.
    $mainTable = $_POST['mytable'];
    $stagingTable = $_POST['mytable'].'_staging'; // All staging tables are named: 'standardtable_staging'.

    // (4) Determine destination DB table's columns and columns to be inserted into that table (based on values of input file's 1st row).
    $columnsMain = Schema::getColumnListing($mainTable);
    $columnsInput = [];
    $columnsInputText = "";
    if (($handle = fopen("$pathName", "r")) !== FALSE) { //"r" parameter = read-only, w file-pointer at start of file.
        $columnsInput = fgetcsv($handle,0,"\t"); // makes an array of the column names that are in the 1st row of TSV file.
        $firstIteration = true;
        foreach ($columnsInput as $columnInput){
            if ($firstIteration){$firstIteration=false;}
            else {$columnsInputText .= ",";}
            $columnsInputText .= $columnInput;
        }
        echo "<br>DB columns to load: ".$columnsInputText."<br>";
        fclose($handle);
    }

    // (5) Create a new empty staging table.
    $statement = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$stagingTable; // we drop rather than truncate b/c we want to re-determine columns.
    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($statement);
    $statement = "CREATE TABLE ".$stagingTable." LIKE ".$mainTable;
    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($statement);

    // (6) The staging table only needs to have columns that exist in the TSV file, so let's minimize its columns.
    $columnsToDrop = [];
    foreach ($columnsMain as $columnMain){
        if (! in_array($columnMain,$columnsInput)){
            array_push($columnsToDrop,$columnMain);
        }
    }
    if (count($columnsToDrop) > 0){
        Schema::table($stagingTable, function($t) use ($columnsToDrop) {$t->dropColumn($columnsToDrop);});
    }

    // (7) Load data to the staging table.
    $statement = sprintf(
        "LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        ESCAPED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES (%s)",
        addslashes($pathName),$stagingTable,$columnsInputText
    );
    echo "<br>Here's the MySQL staging statement: <br>".$statement."<br>";

    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec("SET sql_mode ='';"); // don't actually recall why I put this here.
    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($statement);

    // (8) 'INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' is used here to get data from staging table to the actually-used table.
    // Note: Any new columns in the staging table MUST already be defined in the main table.
    $statement = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT * FROM %s ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ", $mainTable,$columnsInputText,$stagingTable);
    $firstClause = true;
    foreach ($columnsInput as $columnInput) {
        if (strtoupper($columnInput) != "ID"){
            if ($firstClause){$firstClause=false;}
            else {$statement .= ", ";}
            $clause = $mainTable.".".$columnInput." = IF (".$stagingTable.".".$columnInput." <=> NULL,".
                $mainTable.".".$columnInput.",".
                $stagingTable.".".$columnInput.")";
            $statement .= $clause;
        }
    }
    echo "<br>Here's the staging-to-actual-table statement:<br>".$statement."<br>";
    DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($statement);
    echo "<br>New information added to database!<br>";
```